# JButton setlocation not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

I am new to Java.  I am trying to move a `JButton` which is currently centered, so I changed the location to a static location and it hasn't moved.  Any idea?

```
public Main(BufferedImage image) {
    this.image = image;
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Draw image centered.
    int x = (getWidth() - image.getWidth())/2;
    int y = 0;//(getHeight() - image.getHeight())/2;
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "img/visualizerLogo3.jpg";
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    Main contentPane = new Main(image);
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JButton submit = new JButton("Load File");
    submit.setLocation(600, 800);
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setContentPane(contentPane);
    f.setSize(1200,1000);
    //f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.add(submit);
}
```

Comment: *"I am trying to move a JButton"*  Where should it be?  Provide 2 x ASCII art of the GUI.  One in the 'smallest' state, another expanded to show where extra space goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GridBagLayout is dictating the location of the JButton.  To freeform position it, you should set the content pane's layout to null (it is a horizontal FlowLayout by default).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "img/visualizerLogo3.jpg";
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    Main contentPane = new Main(image);
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    JButton submit = new JButton("Load File");
    submit.setLocation(600, 800);
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setContentPane(contentPane);
    f.setSize(1200,1000);
    //f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.add(submit);
}
```